# Не выводится текст в текст бокс c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно вывести в TextBox2 значение переменной encryptedText

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Diplom
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class VigenereCipher
        {
            const string defaultAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            readonly string letters;
            
            public VigenereCipher(string alphabet = null)
            {
                letters = string.IsNullOrEmpty(alphabet) ? defaultAlphabet : alphabet;
                
            }

            //генерация повторяющегося пароля
            private string GetRepeatKey(string s, int n)
            {
                var p = s;
                while (p.Length < n)
                {
                    p += p;
                }

                return p.Substring(0, n);
            }

            private string Vigenere(string text, string password, bool encrypting = true)
            {
                var gamma = GetRepeatKey(password, text.Length);
                var retValue = "";
                var q = letters.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                {
                    var letterIndex = letters.IndexOf(text[i]);
                    var codeIndex = letters.IndexOf(gamma[i]);
                    if (letterIndex < 0)
                    {
                        //если буква не найдена, добавляем её в исходном виде
                        retValue += text[i].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        retValue += letters[(q + letterIndex + ((encrypting ? 1 : -1) * codeIndex)) % q].ToString();
                    }
                }

                return retValue;
            }

            //шифрование текста
            public string Encrypt(string plainMessage, string password)
                => Vigenere(plainMessage, password);

            //дешифрование текста
            public string Decrypt(string encryptedMessage, string password)
                => Vigenere(encryptedMessage, password, false);
        }
        public void imho()
        {
            var cipher = new VigenereCipher("АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ");
            var inputText = textBox1.Text;
            var password = textBox3.Text;
            var encryptedText = cipher.Encrypt(inputText, password);
            textBox2.Text = encryptedText;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите `textBox2.Show();`. Вместо него напишите `imho();`.

Comment: просмотрел сначала комментарий и подумал что это какая-то шутка которую я до конца не понял.... посмотрел код... ну и названия у методов. =(